# Magento 2: How to add block inside block html content through XML file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, blocks, frontend, page-layouts

I have created my custom arithmetic captcha. I want add that captcha to my custom form through xml file without defining in phtml file on custom layout.
For example:

Testimonail submit form:  testimonial_form.phtml  file contains

```
  <form name="testimonial" action="testimonial/post/index" method="post">

 <input type="text" name="name" />
 <!--  I want captcha here through XML --!-->

<input type="submit" value="submit" />  
</form>
```

I want to add my custom captcha through xml before th submit button.  How can i do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **container** for that. [You can check here, how to create that](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Contact/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml#L15)

Now you can use it inside your phtml:

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
```

Your configuration is done. Now you can add separate XML with name **form.additional.info** for captcha.

Comment: Thank you sohel Rana sir.   I have created container inside my block of that form file and called this childHtml thing in template   I need to create <referenceContainer or <referenceBlock for this?

Comment: Now create referenceContainer for this.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I am privilaged to have your response . It helped me.  Can you help me sir with following as well:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262515/magento-2-around-plugin-get-posted-form-value