# Magento 2 Around Plugin get posted form value

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, plugin, address

I am customizing the address form to add custom arithmetic captcha. We are using ClassyLlama\AvaTax module to validate the customer address in Model File.

Now, to validate my custom captcha on server side i have used plugin method **around**.  To validate the captcha, i have to check post data. using around plugin method How can i check posted data response?  I did try **$this->getRequest()->getPostValues()**   and  $subject->getRequest()->getPOstValues()  but it throws call to undefined argument 4 error.

Here is my plugin file code:

```
   class ValidAddressManagement 
   {
   /**
  * @var ValidateInterface
 */
protected $validate;

/**
 * @var RemoteAddress
 */
protected $remoteAddress;

/**
 * @var Config
 */
  protected $config;

   /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
  */
   protected $resultRedirectFactory;

   /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
   */
  protected $moduleManager;

   /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
    */
   private $messageManager;


    public function __construct(
    ValidateInterface $validate,
    RemoteAddress $remoteAddress,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
)
{
    $this->validate = $validate;
    $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
}


/**
 * @param \ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Model\ValidAddressManagement $subject
 * @param \Closure $proceed
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
 * @param null $storeId
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|mixed
 */
public function aroundSaveValidAddress(
    \ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Model\ValidAddressManagement $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address,
    $storeId = null
)
{
      /*Here Trying to get the Post Data Response but it throws error.  How can i get post reponse. */
        $reCaptchaResponse = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValues();
        if (!isset($reCaptchaResponse)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('reCaptcha validation failed, please try again.'));
        }
        $remoteIp = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
        if (!$this->validate->validate($reCaptchaResponse, $remoteIp)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('reCaptcha validation failed, please try again.'));
        }

     return $proceed($address,$storeId);
     }

        }
```

Is there anything i am missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Try using **Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http** for getting request.

```
class ValidAddressManagement
{
    /**
     * @var ValidateInterface
     */
    protected $validate;

    /**
     * @var RemoteAddress
     */
    protected $remoteAddress;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    private $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * ValidAddressManagement constructor.
     * 
     * @param ValidateInterface $validate
     * @param RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        ValidateInterface $validate,
        RemoteAddress $remoteAddress,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->validate = $validate;
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        $this->request = $request;
    }


    /**
     * @param \ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Model\ValidAddressManagement $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
     * @param null $storeId
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|mixed
     */
    public function aroundSaveValidAddress(
        \ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Model\ValidAddressManagement $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address,
        $storeId = null
    ) {
        /*Here Trying to get the Post Data Response but it throws error.  How can i get post reponse. */
        $reCaptchaResponse = $this->request->getParam('YourFieldName');
        if (!isset($reCaptchaResponse)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('reCaptcha validation failed, please try again.'));
        }
        $remoteIp = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
        if (!$this->validate->validate($reCaptchaResponse, $remoteIp)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('reCaptcha validation failed, please try again.'));
        }

        return $proceed($address, $storeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting up the Http Request is also giving same error:  'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http::getPostValues() in

Comment: What about $this->request->getParam('YourFieldName');?

Comment: That Returns empty and if i enter $this->request->getParam()  then we are getting Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request::getParam(), called in

Comment: Also checked  $this->request->getPost()  which is also not working.

Comment: Sorry then, I have no copy of this custom module for checking.

Comment: Ok Sit. Thank you, I figured out this one. Can you help me with this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262909/magento-2-knokout-js-remove-element-define-in-differen-template-file