# Magento 2 Knokout.js remove element define in differen template file

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, shipping, knockoutjs

I want to remove html element from template file using knockout.js code.
I have write my code in shipping.js which is getting called on checkout page.
In shipping.js under  i have defined my variable hideShippingHtml: ko.observable

```
     return Component.extend({
        hideShippingHtml: ko.observable(false),
       isVisible: ko.observable(quote.isVirtual()),
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual()

           ......
     }),
```

on frontend in shipping.html template i called it for the div i want to remove

**Method 1:**

```
       <div if="hideShippingHtml">Jackson Villey</div>
```

**Method 2:**

```
                <div data-bind="visible: hideShippingHtml">Jackson Villey</div>
```

**Method 3:**

```
                <div data-bind="if: hideShippingHtml">Jackson Villey</div>
```

In console getting error that :  ReferenceError: hideShippingHtml is not defined  seems like data-binding error.

What could be the issue?  Any help would be appreciated!